# Homeomorphism in topology

Tags: general-topology

I need to find an homeomorphism between (0,1) and the real line.

Is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x-1}$$ an homeomorphism for this?

Comment: Anyway it is enough to show that it is injective and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=-\infty$. There's a fact that any continous bijection $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: It is differentiable and the derivative is $<0$, hence it is a homeomorphism $(0,1)\longrightarrow f((0,1)) = (-\infty, +\infty)$. It is even a ${\cal C}^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism.

Comment: What properties does a homeomorphism have?  Does this map satisfy those properties?  And, to be pedantic, what are the topologies on $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is continuous, monotonic, and maps from the correct domain to the correct image.  That makes it 1-1 and bijective.

Comment: I've always liked arctans for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Randall For example?

Comment: $\tan$ defines a continuous bijection $(-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$.  Its inverse is $\arctan$, which is also continuous.  You can adjust the argument to make this work as a map $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ pretty easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f$ is clearly continuous, and its derivative satisfies
$$
f'(x) = -\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\right) < 0 \qquad\text{for all $x\in(0,1)$.}
$$
Hence $f$ is injective with differentiable inverse by the inverse function theorem in one dimension. In particular, the inverse of $f$ is continuous. To see that $f$ is surjective, it suffices to note that $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to 1$ and $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0$; by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ is surjective.

Thus we've shown that $f$ is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse, and is thereby a homeomorphism.